# Interpretation of clinfo output with respect to Memory Allocation

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Below is the partial copy of the clinfo in which i have question.

```
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:                     64 MByte
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:                  32 MByte
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_TYPE:               Read/Write
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHELINE_SIZE:           64
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE:               4096
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:                      1 KByte
CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:                      Global
```

1) CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE -> does it represent maximum global memory that a kernel can allocate?.  I am able to allocate more than this.

2) CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE  -> Does it represent the maximum contiguous memory allocation size?. if not, what size it points to ?

3) CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE -> The Local memory Type is  'Global'. This essentially means Local/Global there is no difference. In this case why Local mem Size is 1KB?.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its clinfo? 
On my AMD GPU it looks totally different:

```
Cache type:                                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:                               64
  Cache size:                                    16384
  Global memory size:                            4766494720
  Constant buffer size:                          3376637952
  Max number of constant args:                   8
  Local memory type:                             Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                             32768
```

And there you can clearly see it has 4Gb of VRAM